# Lock object which fields are actually being read

Tags: java, synchronized

We have such situation

```
    class Pole extends Thread
{
    JButton pole;
    Plansza p;
    Pole neighbours[] = new Pole[4];
    public Pole(Plansza p)
    {
        this.p = p; 
        pole = new JButton();
        int r,g,b;
        r=p.rndColor();
        g=p.rndColor();
        b=p.rndColor();
        pole.setBackground(new Color(r,g,b));
    }
    public Pole()
    {
        ;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.yield();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep((int)p.rndTime());
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                ;
            }
            if(p.rnd.nextDouble()<=1-p.p)
                setNeighboursColor();
            if(p.rnd.nextDouble()<=p.p)
                setRandomColor();
        }
    }

    public void setRandomColor()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            int r,g,b;
            r = p.rndColor();
            g = p.rndColor();
            b = p.rndColor();
            pole.setBackground(new Color(r,g,b));
        }
    }
    public void setNeighboursColor()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {

            int r,g,b;
            Color c0 = neighbours[0].pole.getBackground();
            Color c1 = neighbours[1].pole.getBackground();
            Color c2 = neighbours[2].pole.getBackground();
            Color c3 = neighbours[3].pole.getBackground();
            r = (int)(c0.getRed() + c1.getRed() + c2.getRed() + c3.getRed())/4;
            g = (int)(c0.getGreen() + c1.getGreen() + c2.getGreen() + c3.getGreen())/4;
            b = (int)(c0.getBlue() + c1.getBlue() + c2.getBlue() + c3.getBlue())/4;
            Color nc = new Color(r,g,b);
            pole.setBackground(nc);
        }
    }
}
```

I'v edited question and pasted my code, so maybe now its a little bit clearer
each Pole(Field) has is in neighbour relation with 4 other Pole objects so we have many such objects and each is different thread, they can read colour from their neighbours and change it self colour as arithmetic average of neighbours colors.

Comment: Do you have more than one thread carrying out the above loop? Do they use the same instance of whatever `this` is? If they use the same instance then only one `Thread` can enter the `synchronized` block at a time. If they do not then your `synchronized` block does nothing.

Comment: each object of Class X is running loop i forget too add  that class extends Thread

Comment: Do you need this strange singleton-like pattern for some reason? Does that even compile and run decently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without meaning to be unkind, I think you have completely the wrong idea about how synchronization works in Java.

There is no way to "lock an object" in Java.  Your question isn't entirely clear as there's an odd infinite nesting of `X`s going on, so `x[1]` is ambiguous.  But the essence is that if one object tries to assign or read the fields of another, it will succeed in reading/writing.  The only way it could wait is if it chose to synchronize on a monitor beforehand.  (This wait could be encapsulated of course, e.g. if `c` were an `AtomicReference<Color>` or similar - it doesn't have to be done explicitly.)

Also, if there are multiple threads involved, then visibility becomes an issue as well.  You would have to declare the array of `X`, as well as the `Color` variable, as `volatile` else there's no guarantee that updates will be seen by other threads.  Alternatively, if you do choose to go down the synchronization route, and do this consistently, visibility will also be guaranteed (though it doesn't sound like this fits in with your ideas).

I am not entirely sure what it is you're trying to achieve here so can't give any design advice.  I do however recommend the book Java Concurrency In Practice.  Concurrency is **hard**, and it's essential to get your head around it if you want to avoid subtle bugs.  Moreso than any other area of development, it requires an understanding of the principles upfront, rather than just muddling through the issues as they come up.

Answer (score 2):

Andrzej's answer is really good and you should do what he suggests. I will post a simple explaination to get you started.

> What will happen if object for example x[3] lock himself while x[1]
>   will be trying to assign c=x[3].x ?

A data race may occur.

If you want to prevent data races, you have to ensure that all the threads accessing the same variable are synchronized, which means, that the synchronization block in which they access it is locked on the same monitor.

It may look like this:

```
Colection col;
Object colLock;

void accessCollectionThread1() {
  synchronized(colLock) {
    // do stuff with the collection
  }
}

void accessCollectionThread2() {
  synchronized(colLock) {
    // do other stuff with the collection
  }
}
```

That way the two sequences of operations will never occur at the same time and no data races will be possible.

Comment: I think you need to make clear that `colLock` needs to be declared _outside_ of the OP's `X` class and that the same instance needs to be shared across all `X`s. Further, I think that using an `Object` as a lock is really ugly - there are now `Lock` objects that are designed specifically for that purpose. If you cannot find a sensible monitor and need to create one then consider using a `Lock` instead.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think your comment makes it clear:) Personally, I do not like to use Locks if I have no additional reason to. And Lock Interface is, I think, available since Java 5.

Comment: i'v edited my code maybe now u can say if everything is correct